# Limiting execution time of embedded Python

Tags: python, infinite-loop, sandbox, python-embedding

If I embed the Python interpreter in a C or C++ program, as in [this example](https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding), is there any way to limit how long the interpreter runs for? Is there anything to stop the Python code from entering an infinite loop and thus preventing `PyObject_CallObject` (or equivalent) from ever returning?

Similarly, if the Python code creates a new thread, is there anything to stop this thread from entering an infinite loop and running forever?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can see in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallObject), `PyObject_CallObject` has no mechanism for limiting how long the function runs.  There is also no Python C API function that I am aware of that allows you to pause or kill a thread used by the interpreter.

We therefore have to be a little more creative in how we stop a thread running.  I can think of 3 ways you could do it (from safest/cleanest to most dangerous...

#### Poll your main application

The idea here is that your Python function which could run for a long time simply calls another function inside your main application, using the C API to see if it should shut down.  A simple True/False result would allow you to terminate gracefully.

This is the safest solution, but requires that you alter your Python code.

#### Use exceptions

Since you are embedding the Interpreter, you are already using the C API and so could use [PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc) to force an exception to be raised in the offending thread.  You can find an example that uses this API [here](https://gist.github.com/liuw/2407154).  While it is Python code, the same function will work from your main application.

This solution is a little less safe as it requires the code not to catch the Exception and to remain in a usable state afterwards.

#### Use the OS to terminate the thread

I'm not going to go into this one as it is inherently unsafe.  See [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) for some explanations of why.

Answer (score 2):

If You need control lag and jitter in some realtime system, embed "StacklessPython" - Python with support co-routines. Used in "Twisted Web Server".

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to be able to interrupt any actively running Python code block, including cancelling an infinite loop or just some long-running code. In my application, single-threaded Python code is submitted and evaluated. An interrupt request can come at any time. This question and answer were crucial in helping me actually achieve that.

I use the middle approach from @Peter Brittain's answer from July 2016 above.

After I start the Python engine, I retrieve the thread id using the `threading` package in Python code. I parse that into a c long value and save it.

The interrupt function is actually quite simple:
`PyGILState_Ensure()`
`PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(threadId, PyExc_Exception)` using the thread ID that I save from earlier and a generic exception type
`PyGILState_Release()`

So thank you to both the original question and to Peter Brittain!