# Stop embedded Python prompt from C++

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, embedded-language

I'm running Python embedded in a C++ application. The program consists of a Qt GUI and a work QThread where computations happen. The user can chose to run a Python script from a file or to start a Python prompt. Both run in the QThread. The program exits when the python script is done or when we exit the python prompt. However, I want to handle the case when the user requests to quit from the GUI.

If running a Python script I can achieve this by a call to `PyErr_SetInterrupt`(see [Stopping embedded Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420957/stopping-embedded-python)). The Python interpreter stops, and we can quit normally. However, I haven't found a good way to force the Python prompt to quit.

I've tried feeding characters to `stdin` (with `ungetc`) in the hopes that the Python prompt receives them but without success. I do this from an overloaded `PyOS_InputHook` that I use to catch Qt events while the Python prompt is running.

Any ideas how to properly force the Python prompt to exit?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not set up a slot receiver on your `QThread` subclass that will call `PyErr_SetInterrupt` in the proper context for you?

You might achieve cleaner separation-of-concerns if, instead of using QThreads, you run your embedded Python interpreter in a separate process – which you can then `kill` it as you see fit, or at least you can if you’re on a POSIX-y platform; I take it this type of operation is way different on e.g. Windows.

Comment: The problem is that `PyErr_SetInterrput` does not terminate the Python prompt. Separating the python process into a different thread may be a solution but it also adds more complexity that I was trying to avoid. It may be the way to go though.